# Javascript caching and load if modified

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess

I'm developing widget based script based on javascript, where the end user will come to my site copy the script from my widget site something as follows and paste into their site.

```
<script src="text.js"></script>
```

The problem im facing is if i modify anything in test.js file from my side, the changes is not reflecting in users site because of js file is being cached users browsers.This test.js is hosted in apache server.

Im have tried many solutions using .htaccess to set Etags,Cache-control but none of them work. Is there any headers that i need to add/modify in .htaccess. The solutions im looking for is request should check for last modified and load the new js if modified, else load from browser cache(Preferably handle with .htaccess).

This is one of the sample .htaccess i tried .

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
FileETag MTime Size
```

Regards,
Karthi Kumar